# Weird G++/AR Compilation issue

Tags: cygwin, c++, linker, g++, ar

I'm working a patch-set to compile `dpkg` and APT onto Cygwin. I've almost got everything working, but I'm encountering some weird behavior with `ar`/`g++` that I can't explain.

APT's stock Makefile uses some fancy wrapping around a pretty standard
`.cc` → `.o` → `.a` flow for support libraries, which are then linked in with the main code. It works great under Linux. Under Cygwin, however, the linker stage, using slightly different commands, fails in a way that I don't understand.

Why is it that

```
g++ -g -O2 \
    -L../build/bin \
    -o ../build/bin/apt \
    ../build/obj/cmdline/apt.o \
    ../build/obj/apt-pkg/*.o \                                       ← (This is different.)
    -lapt-private -lbz2 -liconv -lintl -llzma -lz
```

works on my system, but

```
ar rcs ../build/bin/libapt-pkg.a ../build/obj/apt-pkg/*.o            ← (This is different.)
g++ -g -O2 \
    -L../build/bin \
    -o ../build/bin/apt \
    ../build/obj/cmdline/apt.o \
    -lapt-pkg \                                                      ← (This is different.)
    -lapt-private -lbz2 -liconv -lintl -llzma -lz
```

doesn't? When I run the second one, `libapt-pkg.a` builds OK, but the `g++` step produces errors of the form:

```
$ g++ -g -O2 -L../build/bin -o ../build/bin/apt ../build/obj/cmdline/apt.o -lapt-pkg -lapt-private -lbz2 -liconv -lintl -llzma -lz 2>&1 | head
../build/bin/libapt-private.a(private-upgrade.o): In function `CacheFile':
./apt/apt-private/../build/include/apt-private/private-cachefile.h:47: undefined reference to `pkgCacheFile::pkgCacheFile()'
./apt/apt-private/../build/include/apt-private/private-cachefile.h:47:(.text+0x1e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `pkgCacheFile::pkgCacheFile()'
```

Shouldn't the two command sequences shown above be functionally equivalent? What's the difference?

Comment: Is `pkgCacheFile::pkgCacheFile()` defined in `libapt-pkg.a`?  If it is, then try moving `-lapt-pkg` after `-lapt-private`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, that works! How did you know that was the problem? Also, I'll upvote your answer if you submit it.

Comment: I applaud Sato for spotting the problem — I didn’t see it — but, now that it’s been identified, I think I can explain it.  `ld foo.o bar.o` loads all of `foo.o` and all of `bar.o`.  By contrast, `ld foo.o libquux.a` or `ld foo.o -lquux` loads all of `foo.o`, and then anything from `libquux.a` that’s required to resolve undefined references in `foo.o` (i.e., in any code loaded so far).  That way, programs don’t get entire libraries loaded into them; they get only the pieces that they need.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  **TL;DR**  If `pkgCacheFile::pkgCacheFile()` is in `libapt-pkg.a` (i.e., it’s in one of the `.o` files in `libapt-pkg.a`), then it will get loaded (unconditionally) when you say `../build/obj/apt-pkg/*.o`, but it will be loaded from `libapt-pkg.a` only if you put the `-lapt-pkg` after the first thing that *calls* `pkgCacheFile::pkgCacheFile()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, G-Man! Also for correcting the question ownership.